# How should I write my app.yaml for my php app deployed to gcp's app engine?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, deployment, google-cloud-platform, yaml

I'm deploying a php app to GCP's app engine and can't make the app.yaml configuration work.

The app has this directory structure:

```
index.php
/sistema
    /js
    /images
    /css
    index.php
    login.php
    otherpage.php
    ...
```

I'm having problems with the pages that are under the 'sistemas' folder. And also would like to access those pages without the '.php' in the url.

I've tried with many handlers, but none of them worked as I wanted.

runtime: php55
        threadsafe: yes
        api_version: 1

```
    handlers:
    - url: /sistema/css/*
      static_dir: sistema/css
    - url: /sistema/js/*
      static_dir: sistema/js
    - url: /sistema/fonts/*
      static_dir: sistema/fonts
    - url: /sistema/images/*
      static_dir: sistema/images
    # Serve php scripts.
    - url: /(.+\.php)$
      script: \1
    - url: /
      script: index.php
```

Comment: What are the exact problems you encountered? Since I copied your configuration and could access the '.php' pages under 'sistema'. As for not displaying the extension you could do something like '- url: /sistema/login script: /sistema/login.php' to access 'login.php'.

Comment: Hi @Maxim thank you for your answer. The problem is that the php pages undes the folder 'sistema' are loading as static files and i'm not sure why that is happening.